# Angular 13 button click on ios 15.5 doesn’t work

Tags: ios, angular, mobile

I’m testing my angular app on safari ios mobile 15.5 and I’m facing a weird issue.
Some buttons click are not working. I don’t understand why.
Does someone heve an idea about this issue?

```
    <button
      (click)="ActionButtonEvent.emit()"
    ></button>
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps https://angular.io/guide/browser-support ?

Comment: IOS 15.5 is the latest version